# Connect MuleSoft to SQL Server with an AD User

Tags: sql-server, mule, mulesoft

I am trying to get MuleSoft to talk to a SQL Server using an Active Directory User.

I have gotten it to connect using a user defined in SQL Server, however our DBAs are saying we have to connect with an AD User.

I am getting "login failed" errors

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL jdbc:sqlserver://AG-Q4Test1:1433;databaseName=T10SRV01 : Login failed for user 'HQ\MuleSoftSvc'

I have tried to connect using my credentials and have received the same error. I can connect using SQL Management Studio with my credentials.

I am using the Microsoft SQL Server Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc.6.2.2.jre8

I am thinking that is because its using [Windows Authentication](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Windows-Authentication-in-Database-Connector-with-Microsoft-SQL-Server-in-Mule4)

But will this work in CloudHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method described in the KB article will not work in CloudHub because applications don't run in Windows. Take into account that you should not make any assumptions on the operating system and platform for applications deployed on CloudHub.

Answer (score 0):

I was able get Windows Auth working from my local runtime using [this](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Windows-Authentication-in-Database-Connector-with-Microsoft-SQL-Server-in-Mule4) article.

After more digging I found this [KB Article](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Does-CloudHub-support-Windows-Authentication-for-the-Database-Connector) from MuleSoft which states that Windows Auth is not supported in CloudHub.